# OData success message even though no new entry?

Tags: odata, sapui5

I have an SAPUI5 application which is deployed to ABAP server and accessible with Fiori Launchpad. I use this app to create a new interaction (OData Service CUAN_IMPORT_SRV) in Hybris Marketing. My problem is that even though the OData call created no new entry (because such entry already exists), I get the success message. When I add invalid data to the upload data, I get the error message.

This is my code:

```
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel("https://hostname:port/sap/opu/odata/sap/CUAN_IMPORT_SRV/", true);

var oData = { some json... }

oModel.create("/ImportHeaders", oData, { 
success: function() { 
    sap.m.MessageBox.success("Interaction successfully created!", {
        title: "Success"
    });
},
error: function() { 
    sap.m.MessageBox.error("Interaction could not be created.", {
        title: "Error"                                
    });
}
});
```

When I run /n/iwfnd/traces it is marked as "successful execution" (even though no new entry was created).

How can it be that the success message appears even though no new entry was created? How can I avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

First thing is to add your business error in the ABAP backend:

```
DATA: 
 lt_bapi_return type table of bapiret2,
 lo_message_container type ref to /iwbep/if_v4_message_container.

#Error handling
if lt_bapi_return is not initial.
#check if an error message is in lt_bapi_return
loop at lt_bapi_return into ls_bapi_return.
if ls_bapi_return-type = 'E'.

lo_message_container = io_response->get_message_container( ).

loop at lt_bapi_return into ls_bapi_return.
lo_message_container->add_t100(
exporting
iv_msg_type = ls_bapi_return-type
iv_msg_id = ls_bapi_return-id
iv_msg_number = ls_bapi_return-number
iv_msg_v1 = ls_bapi_return-message_v1
iv_msg_v2 = ls_bapi_return-message_v2
iv_msg_v3 = ls_bapi_return-message_v3
iv_msg_v4 = ls_bapi_return-message_v4 ).
endloop.

"raise exception
raise exception type zcx_e2e001_odata_v4_so
exporting
message_container = lo_message_container.

endif.
endloop.

endif.
```

**And at UI:**

```
error: function(response) { 
    //response will have message details
    //each message can have business text, technical info, error code.
    sap.m.MessageBox.error("Interaction could not be created.", {
        title: "Error"                                
    });
}
```

You can add this part of code to every redefined method..
better is create a util method and reuse.